# Angular ng-pattern does not check upper character limit of my regular expressions

Tags: regex, angularjs

I am just starting to test out ng-pattern with some regular expressions that I have used in non-Angular projects and have worked fine.  But using ng-pattern they don't seem to work.  For example I have this regular expression that successfully checks for a string of 6-20 characters with at least 1 alphabetical and 1 numeric character :

```
"^.*(?=.{6,20})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*$"
```

However, in my Angular example below it checks everything successfully except it is not triggered when the string goes beyond 20 characters :

```
<div class="controls">
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.Password" id="Password" name="Password" title="Password" required ng-pattern="^/.*(?=.{6,20})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*$/" />
            <span ng-show="form.Password.$dirty && form.Password.$error.required">{{'_PasswordRequired_' | i18n}}</span>
            <span ng-show="form.Password.$dirty && form.Password.$error.pattern">{{'_PasswordLengthAndAlphanumeric_' | i18n}}</span>
        </div>
```

Is there some error I am making in the syntax, or is there some other reason this is not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing an end anchor, and you have one  `.*` too many (at the start):

```
^             # Start of string
.*            # Match *any*  number of characters
(?=.{6,20})   # *Then* check that 6-20 characters follow
<snip>
.*            # *Then* match any number of characters anyway        
$             # until the end of the string
```

This would work:

```
"^(?=.{6,20}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*$"
```

But it would be easier (and more obvious) to do the length check outside of the lookahead anyway:

```
"^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{6,20}$"
```

(which in turn makes me ask why you're imposing such a low upper limit? My KeePass-generated passwords are usually at least 30 characters in length, for example)

Comment: Thanks Tim, I don't claim to have a lot of knowledge when it comes to regular expressions...thank you very much for the helpful explanation :) This is just a learning exercise mainly so the low upper limit is not really an issue.  It seems like Angular is a little more rigorous when it comes to regular expression syntax, as this did work in a non-Angular project.